# Batch Text Snippet Insertion

Tags: batch, text-editing

I have the source code (essentially a bunch of text files) for some software created by a vendor. I have some customizations (essentially some text snippets inserted into the text files) that have been made directly to the source code. I'm finding it difficult to maintain as the vendor upgrades their source code regularly and I have to re-apply the customizations manually. What I would like is some software that allows me to maintain a list of snippets, the file they apply to, and the line in the file where they should be inserted. Then when the vendor sends me new source code I can just point the software at the new version and the snippets will be inserted in the same place they were inserted in the old version. This would work a little like the stash feature in Git. I'd also like the snippets to be stored in some kind of text file format so that I can keep them in version control. Does anyone know of a good tool that lets me do this or something like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several batch text editor/text search and replace tools until I found BinaryMark's Batch Text Editor (https://www.binarymark.com/products/batch-text-editor). It pretty much does what I want but I'm kind of souring on the approach due to the fact that line numbers will change for a lot of the files with every update.

Comment: Since you're already familiar with git, you could use [git patch files](https://mijingo.com/blog/creating-and-applying-patch-files-in-git), but you'll probably still run into issues if the line numbers change.

Comment: That's actually a better option than the tool I found.